# Dynamic route with static part possible in vite-plugin-pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vite

I'm building a Vue.js 3 app with Vite and vite-plugin-pages for the routing. https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages

Is it possible to have a dynamic route with a static part to it?

```
e.g. /@[handle].vue
```

When I do this, it doesn't work and instead falls back to my catch-all route `[...all].vue`

I don't want to put it in a sub-folder, so `/@/[handle].vue` is not an option. I'd like the `@` symbol followed by whatever comes after being a dynamic username.

I managed to do this in another application using Vue router but not sure how to achieve the same thing in folder-based routing via this plugin.

**How I did this before:**

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/@:handle',
          name: 'Profile',
          component: () => import('../views/Profile.vue'),
          props: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the plugin's [`onRoutesGenerated` hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pages#onroutesgenerated) to transform the routes before they're passed to Vue Router.

The solution requires naming the dynamic route parameters with the `@` prefix, so the filename in your case would be `[@handle].vue`:

```
pages/user/[@handle].vue
```

The following Vite config renames route parameters that start with `@`, so that the `@` is moved into the path right before the parameter:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Pages({
      onRoutesGenerated(routes) {
        const transformRoute = route => ({
          ...route,
          path: route.path.replace('/:@', '/@:'),
          children: route.children?.map(transformRoute) ?? [],
        })

        return routes.map(transformRoute)
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

So the route `path` for the example above is transformed from this:

```
/user/:@handle.vue
```

...to this:

```
/user/@:handle.vue
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-plugin-pages-with-at-prefix-in-dynamic-routes?file=vite.config.js)